# How to chain the state in a child back to the parent which in turn acts as a child and returns the value to its parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent

so I am new over here. So I read a lot about Passing back from a child to its parent via callbacks.

But my issue is, for example, Here's a scenario:

I have a Component called Dashboard.js which is indeed a parent component where there is a state called height which I want to change. Now there is another component called SideBar.js where I am passing this state as a prop and in turn, it is passing the value to a component called SideBarContent.js. Now SideBarContent.js has a state called heightSideBar which is populated by this prop, though this is not allowed. Now in SideBarContent.js, I have a button which should increase this state heightSideBar by a factor of 5. Now this state value is required to be sent into firstly SideBar.js and then finally into Dashboard.js so that from there I could update my Dashboard.js state height and can be used accordingly.

Please help me regarding this passing when there is a chain of Parent and Child function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without seeing some code it is very difficult to understand the flow, but the only thing is to multiply the `height` in the parent by a number, you can pass a callback to all the way down and after setting the factor you can invoke this callback with this factor and multiply the hight maybe. You can change the logic according to your needs but the important thing is data will flow top to button and you'll update the parent's state with the callbacks you pass to child components.

Comment: You can pass callbacks as far down as you need to go, but this is a process called prop drilling, and has an optimal solution using react context system. TL;DR You can provide values/callbacks to the reactDOM tree below a component and only the components interested in them can consume them, thus skipping the prop drilling.

Comment: Thank you so much. ^__^ Will supply code from next time sir.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example you can follow. The `Child1` is useless in this situation but I know you have some other things there. Also, as @Drew Reese mentioned in their comment, this is prop drilling. You can avoid this by using other options but in the early days of learning, I think grasping prop drilling is important.

```js
function App() {
  const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(100);

  function multiplyHeight(factor) {
    setHeight(prev => prev * factor);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Height now: {height} </div>
      <Child1 height={height} multiplyHeight={multiplyHeight} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child1({multiplyHeight }) {
  return <Child2 multiplyHeight={multiplyHeight} />
}

function Child2({ multiplyHeight}) {
  const [factor, setFactor] = React.useState(1);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setFactor(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    multiplyHeight(factor);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" onChange={handleChange} value={factor} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go</button>
      </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thank you ..this is really helpful